# How to remove last 3 characters on a row that ends on "and" SSRS 2016 expression?

Tags: reporting-services

I've a report that has a column where some rows are ending with the word "and" . I'm trying to create a condition on Visual studio to remove the word "and" on those rows by using a ssrs expression

The ssrs expression created is giving me an error on every single row

```
=IIF(LEN(Fields!Schedule.Value)="and",RIGHT(Fields!Schedule.Value,len(Fields!Schedule.Value)-3),Fields!Schedule.Value)
```

Also the function refers to a second Dataset created not to the main one so I'm assuming I should put the Dataset name somewhere

Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this expression:

```
=IIF(Mid(Fields!Schedule.Value,len(Fields!Schedule.Value)-3,4)=" and", left(Fields!Schedule.Value,(len(Fields!Schedule.Value)-3)),Fields!Schedule.Value)
```

Comment: Thank you so much , I just modified the # 4 as there was a blank space at the end but the formula did what it was expected. Awesome